# Can you get a refund of "additional charges" in addition to taxes?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, refunds, taxes, hidden-city-ticketing

My friend had a booking with Alitalia from London to Tokyo involving (due to pricing) a Milan-London leg on the return that he's not going to use.

I know the taxes for the unused leg (GBP 22) can be refunded on request, but what about the "additional charges" (GBP 34.20)?

He has completed all legs that he was supposed to use.

Below is a screenshot of the price for the unused leg

[image]

Comment: Might they do a fare re-calculation that more than weighs up the tayes and charges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick search on matrix shows the probable fare that you show. On matrix the fare breakdown for a one-way X fare to be approximately £68 base, £34 YR and £22 taxes. YR is not refundable on non-refundable fare, only taxes and anything else that counts as airport/government fees.

Having said that, although the taxes are likely to be the same, you can't typically take a one way fare for a missing leg to determine what portion might be refundable. The airline also most likely reserves the right to reprice the flight according to the itinerary flown, and therefore might refuse to refund you anything at all if the repriced itinerary is higher.